# Specific database details in docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: docker-compose, prisma

The service I'm using gives you a command to create a docker-compose file. You can then run `docker-compose up` and choose to create a new database.

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.8
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: mysql
            host: mysql
            port: 3306
            user: root
            password: prisma
            migrations: true
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: prisma
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  mysql:
```

This worked but now I need to set a second project with a new database. Even though I chose the option to set up a new database when I run my project I can see it's connecting to my old one:

```
 prisma init
? Set up a new Prisma server or deploy to an existing server? Create new database
? What kind of database do you want to deploy to? MySQL

Created 3 new files:

  prisma.yml           Prisma service definition
  datamodel.graphql    GraphQL SDL-based datamodel (foundation for database)
  docker-compose.yml   Docker configuration file
Next steps:

  1. Start your Prisma server: docker-compose up -d
  2. Deploy your Prisma service: prisma deploy
  3. Read more about Prisma server:
```

Is there something in my docker-compose.yml thats wrong? I belive `default` is the database name so I've tried the following but the same thing happens:

```
        databases:
          default2:
            connector: mysql
```